# Flowplayer getTime() gives me an Object

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I'm using the flowplayer-3.2.10 and when I click on a button, I want to get the time from the timeline into an inputbox. But everytime if I try to do something, I receive an object.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../flowplayer-3.2.9.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function video1 () {
   alert($f().getTime());
 }   
 </script>

</head>

<body>

        <a  
             href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv"
             style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px"  
             id="player"> 
        </a> 

        <script>
            flowplayer("player", "../flowplayer-3.2.10.swf");               
            </script>
    <form>
        <a href='javascript:video1();'>Start</a> <input type="text" name="start_id_0" id="start_id_0" /><br/>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this and it is working as expected.

`$("#start_id_0").val($f().getTime());`

Comment: I don't get it, 
I get --- [object Object] ----